# Записать Xml ответы в датафрейм

Tags: python, xml, pandas

Мне нужно вытащить данные из `Graylog` и создать из них датафрейм для дальнейшей обработки

```
import http.client
import pandas as pd
import json
from lxml import objectify

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("192.125.135.028:3000")
payload = '''{"from": 0,"size": 10000,"_source": ["receiveMessage"],"query": {"bool": {"must": 
{"query_string": {"query": "nmnls","allow_leading_wildcard": false}},"filter": [{"term": {"recType": 
"3"}},{"range": {"timestamp": {"gte": "2020-10-29 10:00:00.000","lt": "2020-10-29 
10:02:00.000","time_zone": "+06:00"}}}]}}}'''
headers = { 'content-type': "application/json" }
conn.request("POST", "/_search", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()

data = res.read()

res = json.loads(data)

i = 0
for m in res["hits"]["hits"]:
  if i == 10000:
     break
 i+=1
 print(m["_source"]["receiveMessage"])
```

В результате я получаю `xml` ответы вида

```
<request>
    <guid>bc94cb431a32d431</guid>
    <type>3</type>
    <body>
        <payments>
            <payment>
                <account>XXXXXX</account>
                <amount>2000.00</amount>
                <idService>XXXX</idService>
                <idTerminal>XXXXX</idTerminal>
                <comission>120.00</comission>
                <date>20201029100149</date>
                <numTrans>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</numTrans>
                <nmnls>
                    <nmnl val="2000">1</nmnl>
                </nmnls>
                <lang>r</lang>
            </payment>
        </payments>
    </body>
    <sign>3cba03091b2f258c0087f405fa</sign>
</request>
```

из этого ответа мне нужен датафрейм с двумя колонками `numTrans` и `nmnls` и вот тут я застряла.
Как вытащить только эти значения и сложить в датайфрейм? Я так понимаю, для начала эти ответы нужно преобразовать в словарь, например, или строку.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(m)
```

создает датафрейм, но весь ответ кладет в отдельную ячейку полностью

Comment: `pd.read_xml` пробовали?

Comment: Приведите `xml` в виде текста, а не картинки, а то даже попробовать ничего нельзя так

Comment: <request>  <guid>bc94cb431a32d431</guid>  <type>3</type>  <body>    <payments>      <payment>        <account>XXXXXX</account>        <amount>2000.00</amount>        <idService>XXXX</idService>        <idTerminal>XXXXX</idTerminal>        <comission>120.00</comission>        <date>20201029100149</date>     
<numTrans>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</numTrans>        <nmnls><nmnl val="2000">1</nmnl></nmnls>        <lang>r</lang>      </payment>    </payments>  </body>  <sign>3cba03091b2f258c0087f405fa</sign></request>

Comment: pd.read_xml пробовала, но m это не xml файл, это просто ответ, поэтому это не работает

Comment: Я перенёс `xml` из вашего комментария в тело вопроса, картинку удалил. Комментарий с текстом XML можно удалить теперь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я немного ошибся, в самой библиотеке `Pandas` нет инструментов для чтения `XML` (хотя я был уверен, что есть), но можно воспользоваться сторонней библиотекой `pandas_read_xml`:

```
# pip install pandas-read-xml

import pandas as pd
import pandas_read_xml as pdx

xml = '''
<request>
    <guid>bc94cb431a32d431</guid>
    <type>3</type>
    <body>
        <payments>
            <payment>
                <account>XXXXXX</account>
                <amount>2000.00</amount>
                <idService>XXXX</idService>
                <idTerminal>XXXXX</idTerminal>
                <comission>120.00</comission>
                <date>20201029100149</date>
                <numTrans>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</numTrans>
                <nmnls>
                    <nmnl val="2000">1</nmnl>
                </nmnls>
                <lang>r</lang>
            </payment>
        </payments>
    </body>
    <sign>3cba03091b2f258c0087f405fa</sign>
</request>'''

df = pdx.read_xml(xml, ["request", "body", "payments", "payment"]) # путь к корневому элементу
```

Тогда в `df` будет вот что:

```
    account amount  idService   idTerminal  comission   date    numTrans    nmnls   lang
nmnl    XXXXXX  2000.00 XXXX    XXXXX   120.00  20201029100149  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX  {'@val': '2000', '#text': '1'}  r
```

В частности интересующие вас поля:

```
df[['numTrans','nmnls']]
```

Вывод:

```
              numTrans  nmnls
nmnl    XXXXXXXXXXXXXX  {'@val': '2000', '#text': '1'}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! сколько облазила про эту библиотеку не видела инфы. Работает!